# Simple technical adjunction question

Tags: ct.category-theory, adjoint-functors

Suppose $F,G$ are adjoint, and $\epsilon:F\circ G\rightarrow Id$ is the counit. Is it always true that$$
Id_{FG}\epsilon=\epsilon Id_{FG}
$$
as maps from $FGFG$ to $FG$?

It's true if you precompose with $F\eta G$, where $\eta:Id\rightarrow GF$ is the unit, then the result in both cases is $Id_{FG}$, but since $\eta$ is not necessarily injective it doesn't imply what I want about the original maps.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, it is not always true. For instance, suppose $G$ is the forgetful functor from monoids to sets. Then $F$ is the free monoid functor, and the two maps in question are
$$((x_{1,1}, \ldots, x_{1,n_1}), \ldots, (x_{m,1}, \ldots,  x_{m,n_m})) \mapsto (x_{1,1} \cdots x_{1,n_1}, \ldots, x_{m_1} \cdots x_{m,n_m})$$
$$((x_{1,1}, \ldots, x_{1,n_1}), \ldots, (x_{m,1}, \ldots,  x_{m,n_m})) \mapsto (x_{1,1},  \ldots, x_{1,n_1}) \cdots (x_{m_1}, \ldots, x_{m,n_m})$$
More concretely, if we identify $F G 1$ with $\mathbb{N}$ and $F G F G 1$ with finite lists of natural numbers, then the two maps are (respectively)
$$(x_1, \ldots, x_m) \mapsto m$$
$$(x_1, \ldots, x_m) \mapsto x_1 + \cdots + x_m$$
which are obviously not the same.

It's worth pointing out that the equation holds if and only if $F$ and $G$ form an [idempotent adjunction](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/idempotent+adjunction). In particular, it is true when $G$ is fully faithful.

Comment: Just a small follow-up: It turned out my functors are not idempotent adjoint, so I had to rework my proof without using this, and now it's much more clear - so thanks again :-)